# Contacts missing when trying to send iMessage

Tags: iphone, messages, contacts

For new message, when I type next to "to", very few of my contacts show up even though I have been texting them for years??? Only their emails are showing up for the majority. Randomly, a few contacts will have a mobile number I can pick to message. Some contacts don't show up at all even though they are marked as "favorites"--all very bizarre. Sending a group text is next to impossible because none of my contacts mobile numbers are showing up.

Answer (score 1):

Also would help to know if this specific device is the same one that's been in use for "years", and whether you've been icloud synching your contacts or not.

I think there’s a simple solution - create an actual Contact for them.

Comment: Sorry--iphone 7. I have had it for 3 years. I have no problem with icloud syncing my contacts as new contacts show up for me to message. I discovered yesterday it might have something to do with deleting my messages...they were eating up so much battery, I have been cleaning them out lately.So, if I delete any text from that person, I am unable to retrieve their name to text them again. Any ideas how to fix that?